# Browser multiplayer gaming - What are my options besides AJAX?

Tags: php, networking, browser

Simply because I worry about abusing AJAX to get real-time functionality.  Seems like there would be a lot of overhead to make that work.

Assuming my only resources are a pre-existing PHP server, what might be a good way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how high-fidelity your game is going to be, but the [Unity3D engine](http://unity3d.com/) has a web player that enables very rich content to be deployed over the web.  With only a PHP back-end though, you'd still be limited to some sort of data transport over HTTP.